# Unknown behavior with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a sample code as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    int n = 0;
};

class B {
    public:
    shared_ptr<A> ba;
};

class C {
    public:
    shared_ptr<A> ca;
    shared_ptr<B> cb;
};

int main () {
    cout << "Hello\n";

    C c;
    shared_ptr<A> a(new A);

    c.ca = a;
    c.cb->ba = a; // MAYBE PROBLEM HERE

    return 0;
}
```

This code was compiled successfully, but when I run, it even doesn't print "Hello".
I'm newbie to C++ as well as smart pointer. Please help me explain the problem here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have initialized `c.ca` but not `c.cb`, so the latter will not point to a valid location in memory when you dereference it via `c.cb->`. Also, it is advisable to initialize shared pointers using `std::make_shared<A>()` rather than using `new A`.

Comment: @JorgeBellon you're right, post it as an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible fix for your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    int n = 0;
};

class B {
    public:
    shared_ptr<A> ba;
};

class C {
    public:
        C() {
            cb = make_shared<B>();
        }
    shared_ptr<A> ca;
    shared_ptr<B> cb;
};

int main () {
    cout << "Hello\n";

    C c;
    shared_ptr<A> a = make_shared<A>();

    c.ca = a;
    c.cb->ba = a; // PROBLEM FIXED in constructor

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour.
You never create an instance of B and on the line `c.cb->ba = a; // MAYBE PROBLEM HERE` you are de-referencing a null pointer, which is UB.

Note that shared pointers are default constructed to nullptr, not the default constructor of the owned type.